# Convert from HBITMAP to IWICBitmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image, bitmap, wic

I'm trying to convert an HBITMAP to an IWICBitmap, and I'm having quite a bit of trouble.  I found the function:

```
CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP();
```

but I can't get it to work.  Here is how I am using it:

```
void camera_avtcam_ex_t::GrabAsyncFrame(ULONG frameId, IWICImagingFactory* pWicFactory, IWICBitmap** outputBitmap, bool* pAbort )
{

        QueueCamFrame();
        HBITMAP transferbitmap;
        GetFeatureAndRunAcquisitionStart(transferbitmap); //returns transferbitmap 
                                                          //as a valid HBITMAP
       //This HBITMAP works, I can save it to a file and/or print 
       //it to the screen and the image is displayed properly

        pWicFactory->CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(transferbitmap, NULL, WICBitmapUseAlpha, outputBitmap);

}
```

Executing that last line of code in the function causes an ***access violation error.***

Right before this `GrabAsyncFrame()` function is called, I create the parameters it needs like this:

```
        ULONG frameId = 0;
        IWICImagingFactory* pWicFactory = NULL;
        IWICBitmap** outputBitmap = new IWICBitmap*;
        bool* pAbort = NULL;

        theCamera.GrabAsyncFrame(frameId, pWicFactory, outputBitmap, pAbort);
```

I'm kind of suspect to setting pWicFactory to NULL, and then using it soon after.  But  I couldn't figure out any other way to initialize the IWICImagingFactory objects.

**So my question is:**  New question is posted below.

EDIT: If I try using `new` to initialize pWicFactory, I get a message saying

> Error: object of abstract class type "IWICImagingFactory" is not allowed.

EDIT2:

After confirming that setting pWicFactory to NULL was the problem, I now need to know how to properly initialize an IWICImagingFactory object pointer.  This is what I'm working with now:

```
            ULONG frameId = 0;
            IWICImagingFactory* pWicFactory = NULL;
/*new code*/CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWicFactory));
            IWICBitmap** outputBitmap = new IWICBitmap*;
            bool* pAbort = NULL;
            theCamera.GrabAsyncFrame(frameId, pWicFactory, outputBitmap, pAbort);
```

**Question:**  *How do I properly initialize an IWICImagingFactory object pointer?*

Comment: So the CoCreateInstance call is failing? Assign the return value to an HRESULT variable and look at its description in the debugger, then edit the question with that description.

Comment: Aha.  I just needed to call `CoInitialize(NULL)` before using `CoCreateInstance()`.  Works fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
IWICImagingFactory* pWicFactory = NULL;
```

is the culprit.

You're passing a `NULL` pointer to the function, which you then try to use, causing the error.

Comment: Okay as I stated in my question I had a feeling that was the problem, but to answer my question, what would be a better way of initializing it?  Using `new` is the only other method I can think of, but I can't do that.

Comment: Try - CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pIWICFactory));

Comment: @xcdemon05 So your question isn't really about the error you have, but how to create this object?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My question was why isn't this working.  I had a feeling initializing to NULL was part of the problem, but I wasn't sure.  Knowing this now,  my followup question is how to create the object.

Comment: @roger_rowland After that line of code, my debugger still says that the value of pWicFactory is 0x0000000000000000

Comment: If you are on Windows 7 or 8 - try 'CLSID_WICImagingFactory1' instead of 'CLSID_WICImagingFactory'.

Comment: @roger_rowland It's not recognized by the compiler :(

Comment: What OS are you on? WIC needs minimum XP with SP2.

Comment: Ok, I suggest that you edit your original question to show the latest code and then we can see what you're doing now.

Comment: Before you can use `CoCreateInstance()` you need to call `CoInitialize(NULL)` (or the later `CoInitializeEx` version). Then before you exit the program, call `CoUninitialize()`. Beware that if you use `ComPtr` to hold your `IWICImagingFactory` pointer, you need to `Reset()` before calling CoUninitialize.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the nullpointer issue, you probably forgot to call `CoInitialize` first:

```
IWICImagingFactory* Factory;
```

...

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // do this during program init / before CoCreateInstance

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&Factory));

// use factory..

CoUninitialize(); // do this before program exit.
```

Note that if you keep your factory pointer in a `ComPtr` (which I recommend), you need to release the factory interface before uninitializing. In that case you should do:

```
ComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> Factory;
```

...

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // do this during program init / before CoCreateInstance

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&Factory));

// use factory..

Factory.Reset(); // do this before CoUninitialize

CoUninitialize(); // do this before program exit.
```

Also be sure to check the `HRESULT` returned by `CoInitialize` and `CoCreateInstance` (omitted here for brevity)...

*EDIT: I now see in a comment that this was indeed your problem. I'll leave my answer though, in case others are as sloppy-sighted as me..*